# Canvas and Bitmap Variables being set to null

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap

I am developing a simple drawing application for android. The structure of this application is simple - it has a MainActivity class which contains text, and a button which inflates the second class, a custom View which contains the drawing.

The code for the main class is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

DrawingView dv;
ViewGroup parent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    parent = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
}

public void crossClass(View v) {
    //setContentView(R.layout.sample_drawing_view);
    dv = new DrawingView(getApplicationContext());
    View viw = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.sample_drawing_view, parent);
    System.out.println("Attempted to Inflate DV");

}


public void refreshCallback(View v){
    dv.refresh();
}

}
```

The most important part of that class is that an instance of DrawingView is created so that a method in the class can be called later, when a button is pressed.

The method (dv.refresh()), is simple.

```
public void refresh(){
    System.out.println("Refresh Command Sent");
    drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    invalidate();
}
```

All it does is draw white over the canvas.

This gives me the error :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method void android.graphics.Canvas.drawColor(int) on a null object reference
```

I did some checking with the debugger, and found that at the point where that method is called, the Canvas and Bitmap variables are null, [Picture Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sELao.png).

However, when I set the breakpoint to just AFTER the class is created, the variables are not null, [Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKkac.png).

I will put the entire Drawing View class code below, but I don't see what could be causing them to become null.

```
public class DrawingView extends View
{
//Constant
public int Colour = 0xFF000000;
public int width;
public int height;

//Drawing Var
public Canvas drawCanvas;
public Bitmap canvasBitmap;
public Path drawPath;
public Paint drawPaint;
public Paint canvasPaint;


public DrawingView(Context context){
    super(context);
    get_dim(context);
    setupDrawing();
    setupUI();
}

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attributeSet){
    super(context, attributeSet);
    setupDrawing();
    setupUI();
}

public void get_dim(Context context){
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)   context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;

}

public void setupUI() {

}

public void setupDrawing() {
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();

    drawPaint.setColor(Colour);

    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(20);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh){
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    System.out.println("ON SIZE CHANGED CALLED");
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

public void handelAction(int action, int x, int y){
    switch(action) {
        case 0:
            drawPath.moveTo(x, y);
            break;
        case 2:
            drawPath.lineTo(x, y);
            break;
        case 1:
            drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
            break;
    }
    {
        invalidate();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event){
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    System.out.println(event.getAction());
    handelAction(event.getAction(), (int) x, (int) y);
    return true;
}

public void refresh(){
    System.out.println("Refresh Command Sent");
    drawCanvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    invalidate();
}

}
```

Comment: The `DrawingView` you're assigning to `dv` in the `crossClass()` isn't ever really used. You're not adding it to the `Activity`'s `View` hierarchy anywhere. Also, it is not the same `DrawingView` instance that you might be inflating in the next line. If you do have one in that `sample_drawing_view` layout, then you need to get reference to that one from the `View` you're inflating.

Comment: Ah, I thought it might be something like that. This has been a problem for awhile, I lack crucial understanding in how this works. Okay. Is there a way I can inflate the DrawingView I just created programically?

Comment: I'm not sure which you mean. If you want to use the one you instantiated with `new`, drop the `inflate()` line, and add `dv` to `parent` with an `addView()` method. If you want to use the one you've inflated, drop the `new` line, and somehow find and assign that `DrawingView` to `dv`; either by using `findViewById()`, if the `<DrawingView>` element has an `id`, or by casting the return from the `inflate()` call to `(DrawingView)`, if it's the only `View` in the `sample_drawing_view` layout.

Comment: YES. THANK YOU. Telling me to use, addView() was exactly what I needed. If you don't mind, I have one more quick question. When I used addView() the DrawingView works perfectly, however the button I defined in the .xml file is not created. How would I create this button manually?

Comment: Use in your OnCreate()

Comment: Well, if you have multiple `View`s in the `sample_drawing_view` layout, it'd probably be easier to go ahead and inflate that instead, and use `findViewById()` to get your `View` references. Inflating that layout will preserve the dimensions, alignments, etc. that you have setup there. If you'd rather do it all programmatically, then you can create a `Button` with `new` like you did the `DrawingView`, and add it to `parent` as well, but you'd have to handle those attributes you had in the XML yourself in code, which can get rather involved.

Comment: Of course, you could just put all of these things in `activity_main`, unless you're intentionally wanting to add them at some point after the initial content is set. Btw, you generally don't want to use `getApplicationContext()` when instantiating `View`s. Use the `Activity` instead - `this`, or `MainActivity.this`, as needed.